# Alternative for index

Tags: python

I have written a function that can switch the first value and the biggest value of a list.

Here’s my code:

```
def change_lst (lst): 
  m = max(lst) 
  index = lst.index(m) 
  lst[0],lst[index],lst[index],lst[0] 

lst = [3, 2, 10, 9]
change_lst(lst) 
print(lst)
```

But could someone show me a way of doing it without using index?

Comment: Yes, there is. Multiple ways, in fact.

Comment: Can you have several times the max? What should happen then?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `.index`?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to avoid the use of `list.index`:

```
def change_lst(lst):
    max_idx = 0
    for idx in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[idx] > lst[max_idx]:
            max_idx = idx
    lst[0], lst[max_idx] = lst[max_idx], lst[0]
```

You can also use `next`:

```
def change_lst(lst):
    m = max(lst)
    max_idx = next(idx for idx in range(len(lst)) if lst[idx] == m)
    lst[0], lst[max_idx] = lst[max_idx], lst[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres another really weird solution...

This creates a new list with the maximum placed at the beginning and the first element following. It will then insert in everything and only skip inserting at the index of the maximum element, thus leaving the element we swapped the maximum with.

```
def changeList(lst: list):
    newLst = [max(lst), lst[0]]
    for i, x in enumerate(lst[1:]):
        if x != max(lst):
            newLst.insert(i+1,x)
    return newLst
```

Comment: Multiple calls to *max()* may not be very efficient if the list is large as the entire list has to be parsed in order to determine the appropriate value. Having said that, I suspect your answer was somewhat tongue-in-cheek

Comment: This is very inefficient

Comment: @LancelotduLac Yes it was, thank you for the information though!